# Optimistic Locking not working Spring Data JPA when updates run at the exact same time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I can't get optimistic locking to work on a Spring Boot 2 project with Spring Data JPA. I have a test that runs 2 simple updates in different threads but they are both successful (no optimistic lock exception) and one of the updates is overwritten by the other.

***(Please look at edit at the bottom)***

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
  
  @Column(name = "UserID")
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "FirstName")
  @NotBlank()
  private String fistName;
  @Column(name = "LastName")
  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;
  @Column(name = "Email")
  @NotBlank
  @Email
  private String email;
  @Version
  @Column(name = "Version")
  private long version;

  // getters & setters
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public User updateUser(User user)
        throws UserNotFoundException {
    final Optional<User> oldUserOpt =  userRepository.findById(user.getId());
    User oldUser = oldUserOpt
            .orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);

        logger.debug("udpateUser(): saving user. {}", user.toString());
        oldUser.setFistName(user.getFistName());
        oldUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        oldUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return userRepository.save(oldUser);        
  }
}
```

and finally this is my test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

  @Test
  public void testConcurrentUpdate() throws Exception {

    String body1 = "{\"fistName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"email\":\"johno@gmail.com\"}";
    String body2 = "{\"fistName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Watkins\",\"email\":\"johno@gmail.com\"}";
    
    Runnable runnable1 = () -> {
        try {
            mvc.perform(put("/v1/users/1")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .content(body1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception in put " + e);
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable2 = () -> {
        try {
            mvc.perform(put("/v1/users/1")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .content(body2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception in put " + e);
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    System.out.println("user after updates: " + userRepository.findById(1).get().toString());
  }
}
```

when the test runs there is only this record in DB (using h2 in-memory):
insert into User(UserID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Version)
values (1, 'John', 'Oliver', 'johno@gmail.com', 1);

These are the logs. I noticed that version is being checked and set in the sql, so that is working fine. update statement is executed when transaction ends, but both transactions are executed successfully, no exception.

By the way, I tried overriding the save method in the repository to add @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) but nothing changed.

```
[       Thread-4] c.u.i.service.UserService     : updateUser(): saving user. User{id=1, fistName='John', lastName='Doe', email='johno@gmail.com', version=1}
[       Thread-5] c.u.i.service.UserService     : updateUser(): saving user. User{id=1, fistName='John', lastName='Watkins', email='johno@gmail.com', version=1}
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.company.app.service.UserService.updateUser]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.company.app.service.UserService.updateUser]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]
[       Thread-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.UserID as Use1_3_0_, user0_.Email as Email2_3_0_, user0_.FirstName as FirstNam4_3_0_, user0_.LastName as LastName5_3_0_, user0_.Version as Version9_3_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.UserID=1
[       Thread-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.UserID as Use1_3_0_, user0_.Email as Email2_3_0_, user0_.FirstName as FirstNam4_3_0_, user0_.LastName as LastName5_3_0_, user0_.Version as Version9_3_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.UserID=1
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[       Thread-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.company.app.service.UserService.updateUser]
[       Thread-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.company.app.service.UserService.updateUser]
[       Thread-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update User set Email=johno@gmail.com, FirstName=John, LastName=Watkins, Version=2 where UserID=1 and Version=1
[       Thread-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update User set Email=johno@gmail.com, FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Version=2 where UserID=1 and Version=1
user after updates: User{id=1, fistName='John', lastName='Watkins', email='johno@gmail.com', version=2}
```

**EDIT:**

I think the issue is because the inserts are done at the exact same time.
I added some this code in the service just before  calling save():

```
double random = Math.random();
long wait = (long) (random * 500);
logger.debug("waiting {} ms", wait);
try {
    Thread.sleep(wait);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With this code, I always get the Optimistic Lock exception, because the inserts are not executed at the same time. Without this ugly workaround I never get the exception. Is there a way to solve this? (other than this workaround). Or I shouldn't worry about this scenario happening in production?

Comment: have you found any workaround solution my friend? I am also having the exact same  problem when updating a a row @damian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimistic Locking ensures that no other changes have been done to an entity between loading and saving it. Since your service loads the entity right before saving it, it is very unlikely for another thread to interfere in this short time frame, which is why you only see a conflict if you make your thread sleep.

If you want to extend the protection offered by optimistic locking beyond a database transaction, you can pass a previously loaded entity to the client and back, and save it without loading it again:

```
  public User updateUser(User user) {
      return userRepository.save(user);
  }
```

(this calls `entityManager.merge()`, which automatically checks the version)

or, if you need more fine grained control over which fields are updated, you can just pass those fields and the version, and check the version yourself when saving:

```
  public User updateUser(UserDto user) {
      User savedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
      if (savedUser.getVersion() != user.getVersion()) {
          throw new OptimisticLockingViolationException();
      }
      savedUser.setName(user.getName());
  }
```

Comment: Hi @meriton I'm already reading the user from repo and then calling userRepository.save(oldUser); so I'm not sure what is the solution that you are proposing, can you please clariify? both threads seem to be reading the record at the same time (before the other thread saved changes) and both have the right version, so that second snippet does not work either.

Comment: Did you read the part about "pass a previously loaded entity to the client and back, and save that **without loading it again**"? Did you notice that your `updateUser` method starts by loading the entity, but mine doesn't? That's the solution I am proposing. Either refrain from loading the entity when saving changes, or check the version yourself.

Comment: And of course the second snippet works. In case both threads read the entity at the same time, both will have the same version. The first thread to commit their update will succeed, but the second thread will fail - either due to a database lock (if the second thread executes its update before the first thread commits), or due to optimistic lock (if the second thread executes its update after the first thread has committed).

Answer (score -3):

You could use `ExecutorService` to manage multithread and `CyclicBarrier` in order to synchronize threads execution(or at least shorten execution time gap between threads).

I did an example making a call to your `UserService` class:

**Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  @Lock(value = LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
  Optional<User> findById(Long id);
}
```

**JUnit Test Case**

```
// Create a Callable that updates the user
  public Callable<Boolean> createCallable(User user, int tNumber, CyclicBarrier gate) throws OptimisticLockingFailureException {
    return () -> {
      // Create POJO to update, we add a number to string fields
      User newUser = new User(user.getId(),
              user.getFistName() + "[" + tNumber + "]",
              user.getLastName()  + "[" + tNumber + "]",
              user.getEmail());

      // Hold on until all threads have created POJO
      gate.await();

      // Once CyclicBarrier is open, we run update
      User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(newUser);

      return true;
    };
  }

  @Test(expected = ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class)
  public void userServiceShouldThrowOptimisticLockException() throws Throwable {
    final int threads = 2; // We need 2 threads
    final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(threads); // Barrier will open once 2 threads are awaiting
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    // Create user for testing
    User user = new User("Alfonso", "Cuaron", "alfonso@ac.com");
    User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

    // Create N threads that calls to service
    List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
      tasks.add(createCallable(savedUser, i, gate));
    }

    // Invoke N threads
    List<Future<Boolean>> result = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

    // Iterate over the execution results to browse exceptions
    for (Future<Boolean> r : result) {
      try {
        Boolean temp = r.get();
        System.out.println("returned " + temp);
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // Re-throw the exception that ExecutorService catch
        throw e.getCause();
      }
    }
  }
```

We use `Callable`, because it can throw `Exceptions` that we can recover from `ExecutorService`.

*Notice, the more instructions are between your thread call and save statement, the more chances are that they will not be in sync to cause a OptimisticLockException. Since you will be calling controller I would suggest to increase the amount of threads for better chances.*

Comment: Thanks Cristian, this is not an internal error but  handling of concurent updates. I'm handling the exception and a proper message is returned to the user, but in this case I'm testing that the api can handle concurrent updates for the same resource

Comment: Hi @Damian, I did replicate the error using this code. Maybe you can adapt it. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this seems more of a workaround to make the test work than an actual solution to the problem. in production the service will be called and I won't be managing the threads